self healing btrfs on top of mdadm raid6
Some sources say that btrfs can self heal when used on top of a mdadm RAID 1, 5 or 6. Is that correct?
This is how it suppose to work:

btrfs detects the bit flip with he help of the checksum when reading an incorrect bit
btrfs reports back to the RAID (in this case mdadm) that a read error happened
due to the reported error, the RAID reads the data from the parity disk
btrfs check the data read and if correct, writes it back to the disk

How can I check if this is the case or not?

Do you have a practical problem you need solved, or are you just trying to understand a theoretical setup better?

I just try to under the theoretical setup. I'm planing to setup a sever with this configuration but before I commit to it, I want to understand its limitations.
